# How to display database records in grails

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0

This is my gsp page

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>GORM APP</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="2px"> 
 <tr>
 <td>EMPLOYEE ID</td>
 <td>EMPLOYEE NAME</td>
 </tr>
  <g:each in="${table}" var="x">
 <tr>
 <td>${x.emp_id}</td>
 <td>${x.emp_name}</td>
 </tr>
 </g:each>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Iam new to groovy grails .Iam try to create employee management application
i tryes

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
<table>
            <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <g:sortableColumn property="employeId" title="EMPLOYEE ID" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="EMPLOYEE NAME" />

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${employeInstanceList}" status="i" var="employeInstance">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">


                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: employeInstance, field: "employeId")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: employeInstance, field: "name")}</td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>`
```